# How to create a modified useSelector custom hook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to create custom hook to remove a lot of boilerplate from reusable code.

My redux setup involves a bunch of combined reducers so getting redux values using `useSelector` from `react-redux` entails quite a lot of boilerplate code.

Let's say I have an `admin` reducer inside my `rootReducer`. I could get one of it's values as follows:

```
const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  const value = useSelector<IRootReducer, boolean>(
    ({ admin: { val1 } }) => val1
  )

  // rest of code
}
```

I want to create a custom hook `useAdminSelector` based off the implementation above so that it can be used as follows:

```
const value = useAdminSelector<boolean>(({ val1 }) => val1)
```

In the definition of the implementation I'd like to have my `IAdminReducer` interface implemented too.

Here's my attempt:

```
export function useApplicantSelector<T>((applicantState: IApplicant): T => (retVal)): T {
  return useSelector<IReducer, T>((state) => (state.applicant)) 
}
```

But this solution is obviously syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
export const useAdminSelector = <T>(adminSelector: (adminState: IAdminReducer) => T) => {
    return useSelector((state: IRootReducer) => adminSelector(state.admin))
}
```

and then

```
const value = useAdminSelector<boolean>(({ booleanVal }) => val1)
```

If I understand you correctly, I think this should solve your problems:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom hood. Read more about [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) or similar.
If you don't want any libraries - just write your custom select function

```
const selectVal1 = ({ admin }: IRootReducer) => admin.val1;
```

and use it

```
const val1 = useSelector(selectVal1);
```

**UPDATE**

What about this?.

[JS]

```
const useAdminState = (key) => useSelect((state) => state.admin[key]);
```

[TS]

```
const useAdminState = (key: keyof IRootReducer['admin']) => useSelect(({ admin }: IRootReducer) => admin[key]);
```