# Is it possible to create a reusable function for useSelector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am curious if there is a way to reuse `useSelector` in `redux` since I use it multiple times in different screens.

I tried creating a `selector.ts` file like this but it did not work since it is not inside the store and not a function component. Any idea how can I reuse this code?

```
export const branch = useSelector((state: any) => state.branchReducer.branch);
```

Comment: You can create customHooks that will always return that value for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414860/how-to-create-a-modified-useselector-custom-hook-with-typescript

Comment: You might be interested in [createSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stick the selector function into a file, then have each component import the selector and pass it into useSelector:

```
// selectors.ts
export const branchSelector = (state: any) => state.branchReducer.branch;

// used like:
import { branchSelector } from './some/path'
const Example = (props) => {
  const branch = useSelector(branchSelector);
  // ...
}
```

Or you could create custom hooks and use those:

```
// selectorHooks.ts
export const useBranch = () => useSelector((state: any) => state.branchReducer.branch);

// used like:
import { useBranch } from './some/path';
const Example = (props) => {
  const branch = useBranch();
  // ...
}
```